# Vim - how can I use smartcase for / search but noic for * search?

Tags: vim

I love smartcase and I love the * and # search commands. But I would prefer that the * and # search commands be case-sensitive while the / and ? search commands obey the smartcase heuristic.

Is there a setting hidden away somewhere that I haven't been able to find yet? I would rather not have to remap the * and # commands.

In summary: I want smartcase behaviour for / and ? but noic behaviour for * and #.

Thank you,
Keith

Answer (score 4):

Not *exactly* what you're looking for, but if you leave `smartcase` off and just prepend your `/` searches with `\c` when you want to ignore case, it's almost the same thing.

See the Case sensitivity section [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Searching)

Edit:  actually according to all the documentation I'm seeing what you want is the expected behavior, however testing it myself it looks like Vim is applying `smartcase` to `*` and `#` as well.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I have tested 7.4 and 8.0 under Linux and * and # ignore the smartcase setting as documented. If I have smartcase set, my cursor is on "Thread", and I type '*', the occurances of 'thread' will be highlighted if-and-only-if 'ic' is set.

Thanks for the reference to the 'Case sensitivity' documentation. It says in part: "When programming, there is generally no reason to want 'smartcase' to apply when you press *. "

This reasoning is sound but the implementation is is still not quite what I am seeking. I want * and # to use "noic" even if I have "ic" and "smartcase" set.

Comment: Happy to help, I understand what you want and the documentation says it should work that way but it doesn't seem to in practice.  If you have 8.0 available, try what Christian recommended `:au CmdlineEnter /,\? :set noignorecase` and `:au CmdlineLeave /,\? :set ignorecase` in `.vimrc` and see if that works.  I don't have 8.0 readily available at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the value of `'ignorecase'` and `'smartcase'` for `*` / `#` and for any ex-command and searching via `/` turn them back on via the `CmdLineEnter` autocmd event.

```
nnoremap <expr> * <SID>star_power('*')
nnoremap <expr> # <SID>star_power('#')
function! s:star_power(cmd)
    let [&ignorecase, &smartcase] = [0, 0]
  return a:cmd
endfunction

augroup StarPower
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdLineEnter * let [&ignorecase, &smartcase] = [1, 1]
augroup END
```

Now if you do a `*` and then do any ex-command then the values of `'ignorecase'` and `'smartcase'` will change. This may not be desirable. You may want to do a `getcmdtype()` to restrict this to only `/` and `?` modes or maybe maybe something more complex with `CmdLineLeave` and/or a timer.

Note: this requires a Vim 8.0.1206+ to support `CmdLineEnter`.

For more help see:

```
:h :map-expression
:h :let-&
:h :let-unpack
:h autocommand
:h :augroup
:h :autocmd
:h CmdLineEnter
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, this works but I'm going to give the nod to Christian for brevity. I may come back to this approach if I find shortcomings to Christian's. The CmdLineEnter/Leave is an clever tool.

Comment: @KeithHanlan, I prefer Christian's solution as well! Since you are doing search-liking things, you may be interested in [traces.vim](https://github.com/xtal8/traces.vim) or NeoVim's `'inccommand'`

Answer (score 3):

> In summary: I want smartcase behaviour for / and ? but noic behaviour for * and #.

It is a bit tricky, since you do not exactly specify which of the options 'smartcase' and 'ignorecase' should apply for which commands. However note, that it is the default behaviour for the  <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd> commands to ignore the ['smartcase'](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'smartcase') option by default.

So perhaps setting `:set smartcase noignorecase` is already sufficient for you? Else you can be a bit more specific using `CmdlineEnter` and `CmdlineLeave` autocommands for the `?` and `/` search commands:

```
:au CmdlineEnter /,\? :set noignorecase
:au CmdlineLeave /,\? :set ignorecase
```

(Something like this, adjust to taste).
Note, this requires the `CmdlineEnter` and `CmdlineLeave` autocommands, that are only available in later 8.0 releases.

Comment: Thank you Christian. This seems to be what I am looking for and is nice and concise.